# Can't target the username and confirm pass (python selenium automation testing)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

link : https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/addEmployee

I am working with Python selenium automation testing. here I am facing an issue. Can't target the username and confirm pass. I want your help to write the correct code in Python for these 2 fields.

#sample
I tried many its one of the last ones:

username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//input[@class="oxd-input oxd-input--active"])[1]')))

username_field.send_keys('TestUsername')

password is working::
Password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]'))).send_keys('madara123')

this is my whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Username"]')))

username.send_keys('Admin')

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Password"]')))
password.send_keys('admin123')

driver.maximize_window()

login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]')))

time.sleep(1)
login_button.click()

driver.get('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/viewEmployeeList')

addbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--secondary"]')))

addbtn.click()




first_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="oxd-input oxd-input--active orangehrm-firstname"]'))).send_keys('employe')
mid_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="oxd-input oxd-input--active orangehrm-middlename"]'))).send_keys('x')
last_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="oxd-input oxd-input--active orangehrm-lastname"]'))).send_keys('ONE')


# wait for the checkbox to be loaded
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="oxd-switch-wrapper"]/label/input[@type="checkbox"]')))

# click the checkbox using JavaScript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox)


 
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//label[text()="Username"]/following-sibling::div/input')))
username.send_keys('your_username')


Password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]'))).send_keys('madara123')

# wait for the confirm password field to be loaded and enter a password
confirm_password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//input[@class="oxd-input oxd-input--active"])[2]')))
confirm_password_field.send_keys(Password)
```

Comment: for username you can try CSS selector as 

    input[name="username"]
or Xpath would be

    //input[@name="username"]

and same goes for password and xpath is:

    //input[@name="password"]

Answer (score 0):

You should not wait by presence, but wait for visibility, as far as after clicking checkbox new block is rendering for some time.

Also you don't need JS to click on checkbox - checkbox itself is not interactable, but upper element `.oxd-switch-input` is.

Here is the code from clicking checkbox:

```js
wdwait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

checkbox = wdwait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".oxd-switch-input"))
checkbox.click()

username = wdwait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'oxd-input-group') and .//*[contains(.,'Username')]]//input"))
username.send_keys("Test1")

password_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type=password]")
for element in password_elements:
    element.send_keys("dsdsdsd1")
```